# Are VPN Routers the same as a Router

Tags: cisco, router, routing, firewall

I'm currently looking at the Cisco RV042 VPN router, and I am wondering if I will be able to setup individual networks with it.

How do I know which routers or firewalls are capable of setting up separate networks?

Comment: FYI, the RV042 only comes with the [Small Business Limited Lifetime HW Warranty](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/general/warranty/LmtdLf_SmallBusiness.html), and this is not a paid support option.  As such, I'm not sure this device is on-topic for the site.

Comment: The specific router probably is off-topic; the broad question is probably worth trying to answer, but it's unclear just what he's wanting to know. Frank, can you explain what you mean by "setting up separate networks"?

Comment: @chrylis, He wants different subnets... as for answering the broad question "of how do you know the device capabilities?"... Read The Fine Manual

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

By separated networks, you mean VLANs?

If so, there is a tutorial provided by CISCO on how to do it: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/routers/csbr/app_notes/RV0xx_an_vlan_78-21017.pdf

Or do you mean separated WANs, perhaps one being the master and the other the backup, or even with load balancing?

Then, there is also a tutorial by CISCO: 
http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/Loginr.aspx?login=1&pid=2&app=search&vw=1&articleid=622

Or do you mean different subnets? That you can find here: http://sbkb.cisco.com/CiscoSB/Loginr.aspx?login=1&pid=4&app=search&vw=1&articleid=673

Answer (score 4):

Yes, VPN routers are also routers. So you just have to carefully read the router datasheet/documentation.

If you are looking to "vpn router", this usually names a small business product, marketed with VPN to make you buy it. I wouldn't expect to have broad capabilities, nevertheless some products allows you to splin LAN into several VLANs or at least use one port as DMZ (basically offering you two "Lan ports").

Answer (score 0):

VPN router is a pretty broad noun to describe networking hardware. When I think of a "VPN router" it could be a firewall, which is used for routing traffic from the internet or WAN connections. Small business class equipment like the Cisco RV042 are not apples to apples when compared to something like a Cisco ASR. 
Whitepapers and manuals are your best friend when you want to understand a products capabilities.....Thorough understanding of the theory behind what makes those concepts work is another piece of the puzzle.
Time to hit the books id say =).